# How can I initiate Ajax request from firefox developer tools?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox-developer-tools

I want to test several Ajax requests after the backend code completed. Now my method is adding a dummy button, an onclick event and an ajax request inside that.

Is there any way I can initiate Ajax request for testing from [firefox-developer-tools](/questions/tagged/firefox-developer-tools) without editing my jsp / frontend?

Comment: Sure, just use the JavaScript console in Firefox's developer tools to execute whatever JavaScript you like.

Comment: If you want to test http responses use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/ addon. And if you want to watch loaded responses, switch the network tab in developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad), Firefox's dedicated tool for executing JavaScript.

From docs:

> Unlike the Web Console, which is designed for interpreting a single line of code at a time, Scratchpad lets you edit larger chunks of JavaScript code, then execute it in various ways depending on how you want to use the output.

Just open up Firefox and hit `Shift+F4` and you are good to go. using `Ctrl+R` you can run your code (*whole code or selected parts*)

BTW you can have Scratchpad as a tab in [dev tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), of course it's not enabled by default, but you can enable that via dev tool options.